# How a compression of gas molecules change their velocity therefore their KE?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, pressure, frequency, gas

How can a compression of gas molecules change their velocity therefore their KE? My intuition suggest me that there should be a change of mean molecule path length and so the frequency they hit the container should rise and that should be the cause of greater pressure. Can we compare this with a tunnel with a particle oscillating between the two entrances of the tunnel. When we shrink the tunnel length the particle should hit the entrances more frequently.Let say we move a wall against them... they will gain twice the velocity of the wall as it ca be considered as infinite mass in comparision with the molecules and if we count how many times the molecule intercts with the moving wall during motion of the wall we get the incease of velocity. So greater the frequency of collisions with the wall the greater the change in velocity of the molecule?

Answer (score 1):

The average kinetic energy of gas particles is proportional to the temperature of the gas. If we compress the gas *without* changing its temperature, then the average kinetic energy of the gas particles will stay constant. There will be no change in the speed with which the particles collide if you increase the pressure (isothermally).

You may have increased the frequency at which the particles strike the container’s walls and each other, which decreases the mean free path, but their kinetic energy will stay the same.

Comment: But, but, but I think the question is about simple compression,  not the isothermal one that requires special pistons etc?

Answer (score -1):

> So greater the frequency of collisions with the wall the greater the change in velocity of the molecule?

If we're being precise, we'd have to know not only the collision count, but the collision speed, since the KE gain depends on the mass and the inbound speed.

But that renders just fine to the expected form here which is that the increase in KE is equal to the work done, and that is Force across a distance.  And for a gas with a greater number of collisions, you'll have a larger force.